# how to search and remove lower values from arraylist of boxofwidgets in c#

Tags: c#, arraylist

How to search  through array list of "BoxOfWidgets" of and remove the widgets with values less than 20 using the method "GetRidOfTheSmallWidgets" in c# without using foreach or any loops.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ArrayList colBoxesOfWidgets = new ArrayList();

      colBoxesOfWidgets.Add(new BoxOfWidgets("Cardboard"));
      ((BoxOfWidgets)colBoxesOfWidgets[0]).colWidgets.Add(new Widget("The blue widget", 12));
      ((BoxOfWidgets)colBoxesOfWidgets[0]).colWidgets.Add(new Widget("The red widget", 15));
      ((BoxOfWidgets)colBoxesOfWidgets[0]).colWidgets.Add(new Widget("The silver widget", 6));
      ((BoxOfWidgets)colBoxesOfWidgets[0]).colWidgets.Add(new Widget("The green widget", 52));


      colBoxesOfWidgets.Add(new BoxOfWidgets("Metal"));
      ((BoxOfWidgets)colBoxesOfWidgets[1]).colWidgets.Add(new Widget("The gold widget", 9));
    ((BoxOfWidgets)colBoxesOfWidgets[1]).colWidgets.Add(new Widget("The orange widget", 115));
    ((BoxOfWidgets)colBoxesOfWidgets[1]).colWidgets.Add(new Widget("The pink widget", 1));


    colBoxesOfWidgets.Add(new BoxOfWidgets("Metal"));
    ((BoxOfWidgets) colBoxesOfWidgets[2]).colWidgets.Add(new Widget("The grey widget", 12));
    ((BoxOfWidgets) colBoxesOfWidgets[2]).colWidgets.Add(new Widget("The black widget", 15));
    ((BoxOfWidgets) colBoxesOfWidgets[2]).colWidgets.Add(new Widget("The white widget", 19));
    ((BoxOfWidgets) colBoxesOfWidgets[2]).colWidgets.Add(new Widget("The brown widget", 60));
    ((BoxOfWidgets) colBoxesOfWidgets[2]).colWidgets.Add(new Widget("The peach widget", 16));

    GetRidOfTheSmallWidgets(colBoxesOfWidgets);
}

    public static ArrayList GetRidOfTheSmallWidgets(ArrayList colBoxesOfWidgets)
    {
        //It should remove all widgets that have lengths lower than 20.
        return colBoxesOfWidgets;
    }
```

Comment: @SouthShoreAK - Yes, it does.

Comment: Why is it a requirement not to use any loops?

Comment: @Oded Technically yes, it is a loop. Not sure if it would be for the purpose of his question, though. To be honest I can't think of a way to move through a list without *some* kind of loop at some level, even if it doesn't show in the code.

Comment: @SouthShoreAK - True. It was an indirect way to say that there isn't enough information in the question in order to give a meaningful answer.

Comment: If recursion is allowed, I can do it without a loop..

Comment: @jdv-JandeVaan good point, hadn't considered recursion.

Comment: Homework? And, BTW, ArrayList is obsolete...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an if and a goto statement if you like to be funny.